# Node.exe being deleted

Tags: node.js, npm

I've hit a very strange issue with my windows 7 computer when trying to use node.js

Every now and then, when I run a node based command i.e. `npm, grunt, yo` I get an `Access is denied.` message, node.exe proceeds to then delete itself, and is no longer a recognizable command.

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Has anyone hit this issue? The last time this happened was when I tried to install yo globally. It crashed, then node.exe disappeared from the installation directory. The error/log trace doesn't seem to show anything other than the installation failed.

```
27389 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
27390 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "yo" "-g"
27391 error node v0.12.7
27392 error npm  v2.11.3
27393 error code ELIFECYCLE
27394 error yo@1.4.8 postinstall: `yodoctor`
27394 error Exit status 1
27395 error Failed at the yo@1.4.8 postinstall script 'yodoctor'.
27395 error This is most likely a problem with the yo package,
27395 error not with npm itself.
27395 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
27395 error     yodoctor
27395 error You can get their info via:
27395 error     npm owner ls yo
27395 error There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just modifying the PATH?

Comment: What directory are you installing node.exe into?  Do you have full privileges there?  I've seen cases where Windows will auto-restore from backup some directories if those directories are modified inappropriately.  I wonder if it will make a difference if you install node from an admin login?

Comment: @GeorgeSimms I am sure, the node.exe is being removed, the nodejs directory still exists in the PATH variable.

@jfriend00 It's installed in the default location `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to switch off your antivirus-software while running node on your windows computer. Some antiviruses detect node as an unsafe program.

Comment: You were right, for some reason it was triggering my antivirus while it worked perfectly fine on all my coworkers machines.